ChecklistBox to ListView in VB
I'm working on a Visual Basic project and I need help with my code.
My problem is I have a ListView with four columns, and I want to display the checked items from a ChecklistBox (named "Extra") in the fourth column of the ListView. [image] This is the form
This is my code
Public Class Form1
    Dim CurrentItem As Integer = 0
    Private Sub btnAddBurger_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddBurger.Click
        If optChicken.Checked Then
            lstOrderView.Items.Add("Chicken")
        Else
            lstOrderView.Items.Add("Ground Beef")
        End If

        If optFries.Checked Then
            lstOrderView.Items(CurrentItem).SubItems.Add("Fries")
        ElseIf optOnionRing.Checked Then
            lstOrderView.Items(CurrentItem).SubItems.Add("Onion Ring"
        End If

        If optWater.Checked Then
            lstOrderView.Items(CurrentItem).SubItems.Add("Water")
        ElseIf optCoke.Checked Then
            lstOrderView.Items(CurrentItem).SubItems.Add("Coke")
        ElseIf optLemonade.Checked Then
            lstOrderView.Items(CurrentItem).SubItems.Add("Lemonade")
        End If
    End Sub


[image] This is the result.
What I expect is When I check items in the ChecklistBox, those items should appear in the "Extra" column of the ListView. How can I write the code to achieve this? Are there any specific methods or events I should use?

I don;t see any effort to implement anything in your code, so there's nothing for us to help with, because there's no actual problem. Instead of expecting code to materialise out of nowhere, you need to put the time and effort into think about what the code to actually do first. That means not just the end result but the steps to get there. You can and should implement each of those steps individually, so the fact that you don't seem to know what the steps even are means that you haven't done that. The first step would be to get the values from the CheckedListBox. How would you do that?

Once you've got the values, then you need to combine them into a single String. Again, you can implement that indpendently of getting the values because it will be the same no matter where the values come from. How would you do that? Finally, you need to put that String into the ListView. You're already doing that part with other data, so you obviously don't even need our help with that. This is why you need to drill down and identify where exactly the issue is. The ListView is irrelevent to your problem here.

Thank you for your response. However, I’m sorry, but I didn’t quite understand what you said. Konstantin Makarov provided the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

What part do you not understand? Copying and pasting code that has no accompanying explanation is not the way to learn. To learn you need to understand and understanding takes some effort. That code does what I said, so what exactly about what I said do you not understand?

This is the shortest way I could think of:
lstOrderView.Items(CurrentItem).SubItems.Add(
    String.Join(", ", From i In optExtras.CheckedItems))

Explanation of this code:

CheckedItems - Collection of checked items in CheckedListBox (CheckedItemCollection).
From .. In .. - Specifies variable and a collection to query. (This is a necessary intermediate operation, because String.Join doesn't work with CheckedItemCollection directly).
String.Join - Concatenates the members of a collection, using the specified separator between each member.


this worked! thank you.

@user27784472, You're welcome. Here's another small simplification: lstOrderView.Items.Add(IIf(optChicken.Checked, "Chicken", "Ground Beef"))

lstOrderView.Items(CurrentItem).SubItems.Add(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Switch(optWater.Checked, "Water", optCoke.Checked, "Coke", optLemonade.Checked, "Lemonade"))

Maybe it would be better to explain your code rather than providing something to copy and paste with little to no understanding.

@jmcilhinney, Is that enough? In my opinion, it is better to immediately push the programmer on the right path, and then he will figure it out himself, if there is a desire. Nobody canceled the F1 key. A lot of programmers (and their teachers) still don't know anything about enumerations and queries and consider for .. if loops to be the only solution.
